# TeXstudio keeps crashing

Tags: texstudio

This just started happening, but it is happening often enough to be quite annoying. It crashes when I am simply in the middle of editing the file I'm working on, which isn't especially large. A box pops up saying TeXstudio stopped working and tells me to close it so that a report can be sent to Microsoft. There's no option other than to close it at this point.

Before going into great details to try to figure out what is wrong, let me just ask if it might help to uninstall TeXstudio and re-install it? If yes, how can I do this without losing or messing up anything (such as settings, files, etc.)?

Comment: are you using latest version? If not, download and try the newest version. It will use same configuration you had as they are stored in different location (on windows, under your user account) so you will not lose the configuration made.

Comment: Oh, thank you, @Nasser. I'll see if that fixes the problem. I thought I had TeXstudio set for automatic updates, but apparently not. Is there a way to have it do that automatically?

Comment: I never seen it update automatically, but it does give a pop-up message once in a while saying that there is a newer version available. I think it is in the setting somewhere. But then I would manually download the newer version and install it each time.